# Custom Tableview cell width issue

Tags: ios, swift

[image: After changing the opacity][image: IB Screen Shot]I'm changing the background colour of the labels dynamically, the width of the cell seems to be static and is working properly in case of 6s only, the background colour fades if the size of the display increases

```
cell.container.layer.backgroundColor = GetColor().randomColor(indexPath.row).colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5).CGColor
cell.title.layer.backgroundColor = GetColor().randomColor(indexPath.row).colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8).CGColor
```

New Code// after changing the opacity

//        cell.container.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.85).CGColor
        cell.title.backgroundColor = GetColor().randomColor(indexPath.row).colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)

[image]

Comment: please explain your issue in detail ....

Comment: See the screenshot

Comment: ya but whats the problem in that

Comment: the background colour on the right is faded

Comment: how you are setting background color?

Comment: cell.container.layer.backgroundColor = GetColor().randomColor(indexPath.row).colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5).CGColor
        cell.title.layer.backgroundColor = GetColor().randomColor(indexPath.row).colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8).CGColor

Comment: it seems that your issue is related to AutoLayout please share your screen.

Comment: You might use cell.contentView.layer.backgroundColor = GetColor().randomColor(indexPath.row).colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5).CGColor

Comment: is this worked for you @MohitArya

Comment: No still not working @rishi

Comment: Maybe you have an object in front ow the cell? Like a UIView with a white tint?

Comment: there are just three objects a container view, a title label and a description label

Comment: everything works fine on changing the opacity to zero

Answer (score 1):

Mohit Arya,

I beilieve you have applied Autolayout constraint on the label inside the cell :) If yes please verify if its the same as I have shown below if not please add autolayout constraints properly,

[image]

As you are setting the color of the label itself and want it to cover the whole cell setting all the four constraint to 0 is necessary

**EDIT:**

Now as per your comment, if constraints are same as I have given below your label must be covering the whole cell :)

Then all you have to do is to

```
[cell.label setBackgroundColor: GetColor().randomColor(indexPath.row).colorWithAlphaComponent(1.0)]
cell.label.opaque = YES;
```

Comment: @mohit-arya : Why dont you simply set the background color of label as I have written in my editted answer?? Its worth a try :)

Comment: @mohit-arya : Not a great idea though but can you please change label's opaque property to YES ???

Answer (score 0):

Check background color (and background color alpha value) for all views in your cell view hierarchy. For example, issue like this can appear if your cell's contentView have background color with alpha < 1, and your label (which size don't fit contentView) have same background color. Thats all what we can say by information you provided.

So, use different colors, or use alpha = 1, or use clear color in label.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution..the following code was interfering with the UI, I still don't know why the container.bounds is not returning the actual width

```
        container.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
    container.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    container.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    container.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    container.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: container.bounds).CGPath
```